Permission denied error for executing scripts from remote URL on Rundeck
I have an issue when I try to run script from remote URL on my Rundeck jobs. The script path is /home/ubuntu/rundeck/test-job.sh
When I execute this script, its giving below error.
Execution failed: 56 in project Test-Environment: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [test-rundeck.dom.net: IOFailure: error writing to tempfile: /home/ubuntu/rundeck/test-job.sh (Permission denied) + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {test-rundeck.dom.net=[IOFailure: error writing to tempfile: /home/ubuntu/rundeck/test-job.sh (Permission denied) + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]```


The problem is that the directory "/home/ubuntu/rundeck/" is inaccessible by user "rundeck". Check this thread, it seems to be the same issue: https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/DxtU2r974Nw

Yeah, I came across similar issues. But I have 3 different Rundeck apps running on 3 different instances. I didn't face this issue. I am facing this problem on only one of the Rundeck. Is there any solution for this error?
I placed the script files under var/lib/rundeck/ with owner as rundeck, then its working well.

The issue which arised is on Rundeck version 5.1.1 and other Rundecks are with versions 4.10, 4.11 and 5.40
Can we overcome this problem with any other solution not the one which I mentioned?

Following your comments, a good practice is to put your scripts in a "neutral" space like /opt/scripts or something and give read/execute permissions to the rundeck user, /home/ubuntu is the ubuntu user space, and the rundeck user can't reach it.
